# JavaScript: Set border radius

Tags: javascript

How can I set the -moz-border-radius with pure JavaScript (no jQuery, no plugins etc)?

```
document.getElementById('id')
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.borderRadius = '1em'; // w3c
document.getElementById('id').style.MozBorderRadius = '1em'; // mozilla
```

But why not do it in a stylesheet?

Comment: Okay, that works, thank you! How do I do that now for webkit?
PS: I want to keep my css valid.

Comment: style.WebkitBorderRadius = '1em'; // WebKit
(Elijah Grey say this).
And don't you want to accept an answer?

Answer (score 26):

```
var myElementStyle = document.getElementById('id').style;

myElementStyle.borderRadius = '1em'; // standard
myElementStyle.MozBorderRadius = '1em'; // Mozilla
myElementStyle.WebkitBorderRadius = '1em'; // WebKit
```